# paste0() changes format of date

Tags: r, for-loop, format

I couldn't find a duplicate of this, but I can't imagine I'm the only person who has run into this issue.

I'm trying to pull some data from an API, iterating over the dates in the link.  I'm using a `paste0()` in my `GET()` and that seems to be the source of my issue. I've included some sample code below demonstrating how I've set up my code.  I also ran a for loop to print out exactly what the code was doing, and found that the date is being pasted in a different format.  The API needs the dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD, as I've done in my first line of code here.

Structure of current codee

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-02-13"), by = "days")

> date
 [1] "2021-01-13" "2021-01-14" "2021-01-15"
 [4] "2021-01-16" "2021-01-17" "2021-01-18"
 [7] "2021-01-19" "2021-01-20" "2021-01-21"
[10] "2021-01-22" "2021-01-23" "2021-01-24"
[13] "2021-01-25" "2021-01-26" "2021-01-27"
[16] "2021-01-28" "2021-01-29" "2021-01-30"
[19] "2021-01-31" "2021-02-01" "2021-02-02"
[22] "2021-02-03" "2021-02-04" "2021-02-05"
[25] "2021-02-06" "2021-02-07" "2021-02-08"
[28] "2021-02-09" "2021-02-10" "2021-02-11"
[31] "2021-02-12"

for(i in date){
  data <- GET(paste0('https://API_Address/', i,'/More_API_Address')),
              authenticate(user = 'user_name', password = 'my_password')
    )
  
  data_content <- content(data)
}
```

Printing out what's happening here

```
for(i in date){
   print(paste0("paste0('https://API_Address/',", i,"'/More_API_Address')), authenticate(user = 'user_name', password = 'my_password')")
  
}

[1] "'paste0('https://API_Address/',18640'/More_API_Address'), authenticate(user = 'user_name', password = 'my_password')"
[1] "'paste0('https://API_Address/',18641'/More_API_Address'), authenticate(user = 'user_name', password = 'my_password')"
[1] "'paste0('https://API_Address/',18642'/More_API_Address'), authenticate(user = 'user_name', password = 'my_password')"
....
```

I tested some individual dates out and everything seems to be working.  Is there a better way to iterate over these dates?

An ideal print out of the API endpoint would be like this: `https://API_Address/2021-01-01/More_API_Address`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option can be

```
for(i in as.character(date)){
  print(paste0("paste0('https://API_Address/',", i,"'/More_API_Address')), authenticate(user = 'user_name', password = 'my_password')"))
}
```

`as.character` will coerce the entire vector, it's a one-stop solution, nothing else needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sprintf` to create the links

```
links1 <- sprintf('https://API_Address/%s/More_of_API_Address', date)
head(links1)
#[1] "https://API_Address/2021-01-01/More_of_API_Address" "https://API_Address/2021-01-02/More_of_API_Address"
#[3] "https://API_Address/2021-01-03/More_of_API_Address" "https://API_Address/2021-01-04/More_of_API_Address"
#[5] "https://API_Address/2021-01-05/More_of_API_Address" "https://API_Address/2021-01-06/More_of_API_Address"
```

Then loop over the links and apply the `GET`

```
out <- vector('list', length(date))
for(i in seq_along(out)){
   tmp <- GET(links1[i],
          authenticate(user = 'user_name', password = 'my_password'))
   out[[i]] <- content(tmp)
   }
```

---

Or another option is to use `lapply`

```
out1 <- lapply(links1, function(link) {
           tmp <- GET(link, authenticate(user = 'user_name',
                password = 'my_password'))
           content(tmp)
          })
```

---

Or with `paste`

```
links1 <- paste0('https://API_Address/', date, '/More_of_API_Address')
```

NOTE: Both `sprintf` and `paste` are vectorized.  So, we don't need loop to `paste`.  In the OP's post with `paste0(` was also included in the string

Comment: Thank you!  I spotted an error in my sample code.  I will adjust it. but in theloop where I use a for loop to print out, that's how the code is structured, with the `paste0()` and that's where the date format is being converted.

Comment: @pkpto39 The `"'paste0(` is not needed because it is not evaluated